# Align vertically Icon and TextInput

Tags: android, android-layout, react-native

I am trying to align vertically `TextInput` with `Icon`s and I tried various style rules, but it doesn't work. In iOS, layout is correct, but in Android elements are not aligned vertically.

```
<View style={styles.headerContainer}>
  <TextInput
    style={styles.input}
    autoCorrect={false}
    onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({ searchTextInputVal: value })}
    returnKeyType="search"
    placeholder="Type Here..."
    value={this.state.searchTextInputVal}
    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
  />
  <Icon
    size={25}
    style={[styles.icon, styles.searchIcon]}
    name="search"
    color={Colors.grey}
  />
  <Icon
    size={25}
    style={[styles.icon, styles.clearIcon]}
    name="close"
    onPress={this.onClearTextInput.bind(this)}
    color={Colors.grey}
  />
</View>

input: {
    paddingLeft: 35,
    paddingRight: 19,
    margin: 8,
    borderRadius: 3,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    borderColor: Colors.grey,
    borderWidth: 1,
    fontSize: 16,
    color: Colors.darkBlue,
    height: 40,
    ...Platform.select({
      ios: {
        height: 40,
      },
      android: {
        borderWidth: 0,
      },
    }),
  },
  searchIcon: {
    left: 16,
    color: Colors.grey,
  },
  clearIcon: {
    right: 16,
    color: Colors.grey,
  },
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't notice I had another style:

```
icon: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    position: 'absolute',
    color: 'white',
    top: 15.5,
    ...Platform.select({
      android: {
        top: 20,
      },
    }),
  },
```

When I removed:

```
top: 15.5,
        ...Platform.select({
          android: {
            top: 20,
          },
        }),
```

and added: `justifyContent: 'center'`, it works now.

Answer (score 1):

The TextInput component in android has by default some paddings & margins, that are added to the ones that you set in the input style. If you use Toggle Inspector option, you might see them.